# Dart code doesn't run in vs code with this error: Setting VM flags failed: Unrecognized flags: enable-asserts

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, assert, manjaro

I have started to learn dart, when I try to run dart code in vs code, I get the error saying that "Setting VM flags failed: Unrecognized flags: enable-asserts", I got the same error in IntelliJ. I use a Manjaro Linux desktop and have no problem when running code in terminal. Any idea?

I can't find a solution!

Comment: Uninstall Dart from your package manager and instead install it manually. The `dart` package coming from Arch are getting quite old and current version also have major issues: https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/dart/-/issues/1 . Instructions for manual installation can be found here: https://dart.dev/get-dart which also have links do download: https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive